# defining a fixed width of p in which image is floated to right

Tags: html, css

I have the following html

```
<p><img src="" />some text here</p>
```

The image is floated to right and has a fixed width and height. But the problem is that I want to reduce the width of the texts only suppose from 900px to 400px but image also shifts to leftwards. Here I need the image to be at right without shifting to leftwards **without touching up markup** or **wrapping whole with a div**. Any idea?

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/47p46/1/)

Comment: As like this http://jsfiddle.net/rohit_azad/47p46/2/

Comment: Does it help if you add a `margin-left: 200px;` to the `img`?

Comment: Can u show screen shoot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your text in a span. Give it any width you want.

Edited you jsfiddle:

```
<p><img src="" /><span>some text here</span></p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shubham59/HRHJw/1/

Enjoy !!!

Comment: I was about to delete my question. anyway you answered the question cleverly that I should accept the answer.